# Jasny multiple file upload with other form elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I try to use Jasny fileupload to pass multiple files to php inside of a form, which on submit event should be uploaded via ajax posted datas. But I can't get it to work. I can not append jasny uploads to posted datas.

If there is a better workaround what would be better to implement instead jasny I would like to know about.

I init my upload fields as follows

```
jQuery('.fileupload').fileupload({});
```

I try to catch theme on submit

```
wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      //here When I serialize the form I do not get the files
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar showing more of your code.

Comment: sorry I will try to refresh this issue. At that time I choose another workaround

Comment: how does your form look like? Do you have proper enctype?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
  data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

So now you have a FormData object, ready to be sent along with the XMLHttpRequest.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'php/upload.php',
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: With Safari 5/Firefox 4, it’s easiest to use the FormData class:

Answer (score 2):

Please look at jQuery File Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), it's support multiple files uploading and have backend implemented for PHP.

Comment: this is what I was using at that time and seems to do the job

Answer (score -2):

Let's go 
1st  you  need put the multiple  at  your input file
2sd 
you  will need use the canvas and sent one by  one at an loop in your script

 give  one look at https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/canvas/ 
http://canvasquery.com/